# Can't get AnyOrigin to load int iframe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use AnyOrigin to load a url into my iframe:

**Problem**: It loads an empty frame, what am I doing wrong?

**Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=google.com&callback=?', function(data){
    $('#output').html(data.contents);
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="output"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyorigin uses JSONP, so you don't load it using an AJAX call.  Instead, the `callback` query parameter should be a function name, and you should load it like a regular script tag:

```
<script src="http://anyorigin.com/get?url=google.com&callback=myCallbackFunction"></script>
```

When the script is loaded, it will automatically execute a function with the name that you specified in the callback query parameter.  Of course, for it to work you need a function defined like so:

```
<script>

    function myCallbackFunction(myData) {
         //myData.contents has your html, do something here
    }

</script>
```

Please note that the function **must be defined before the script**, so either the script needs to be embedded dynamically or you need to define the function before the script.

There are a few tricky parts, such as how you were populating the iframe, and how the function callback needs to be declared, so I've included a full example here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myCallbackFunction(myData) {
    $(function() {
        $("#test").contents().find('html').html(myData.contents);
    });
}
</script>
<script src="http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://google.com/&callback=myCallbackFunction"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<iframe id='test' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>

</html>
```

Note that I've wrapped the call to updating the iframe's contents in a jquery document onload event.  If that's not done, then the call will attempt to populate the iframe before it exists, and will silently fail.